# --numeric-ports option for netstat

Tags: netstat

```
$ netstat --version
net-tools 1.60
netstat 1.42 (2001-04-15)
Fred Baumgarten, Alan Cox, Bernd Eckenfels, Phil Blundell, Tuan Hoang and others
+NEW_ADDRT +RTF_IRTT +RTF_REJECT +FW_MASQUERADE +I18N
AF: (inet) +UNIX +INET +INET6 +IPX +AX25 +NETROM +X25 +ATALK +ECONET +ROSE 
HW:  +ETHER +ARC +SLIP +PPP +TUNNEL -TR +AX25 +NETROM +X25 +FR +ROSE +ASH +SIT +FDDI +HIPPI +HDLC/LAPB +EUI64 

$ netstat --wide --inet | head -5
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.11:38752      jl-in-f188.1e100.net:https ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.11:50882      lga15s44-in-f14.1e100.net:https ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.11:45874      151.101.1.69:https      ESTABLISHED
```

According to the netstat man page on my Ubuntu Linux:

```
   --numeric-ports
       shows numerical port numbers but does not affect the resolution of host or user names.
```

Yet, that option seems to affect the resolution of host names, too.

```
$ netstat --wide --inet --numeric-ports | head -5
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.11:38752      209.85.200.188:443      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.11:50882      172.217.1.78:443        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.11:45874      151.101.1.69:443        ESTABLISHED
```

I expected to see host names and port numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I have `net-tools 1.60_p20170221182432` (Gentoo) and it works as documented, so there may be a bug in the version that you have. If you have `ss` available, you can get very similar results using `ss -4rn` (`-4`: IPv4 only, `-r`: resolve names, `-n`: numeric service numbers); the difference will be the order that the data are displayed and some formatting details.